# How to make a simple counter in VBscript -> MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

How to make a simple counter in VBscript counting from 0, 1, 2, etc. to infinity ... that each number was entered in another record in the database MSSQL ID column?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an [`IDENTITY` field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174979%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) on the application side? If so: don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by the `Do Until` loop starting from 0 to execute up to infinity, check the condition as `i = -1`.

Then you can use the `i` value in your required purpose

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
  i = 0
  Do Until i = -1
    Document.write(i)
    ' Use for the MSSQL ID column
    i = i + 1
  Loop
</script>
```